# MySQL said: Host '10.10.10.121' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, sequelpro

In my office, there is a desktop computer which is CentOS7.2 system, there installed MySQL on it.

and in my computer, I have a Sequel Pro on it.

I want to use the Sequel Pro to connect the desktop computer's mysql.

But there gets this error:

[image]

```
Unable to connect to host 10.10.10.127, or the request timed out.

Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10 seconds).

MySQL said: Host '10.10.10.121' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

The desktop computer ip is `10.10.10.127`, mine is `10.10.10.121`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your situation, you should set the remote login user privileges in your mysql:

1. In your desktop computer, you login to the mysql:

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```
2. grant the priviliges

   ```
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on yourDB.* to 'root'@'10.10.10.121'  IDENTIFIED BY 'the password';
   ```
3. `flush privileges`

Then you can use the tool to connect the desktop computer's mysql in your computer.

You'd better fixed the desktop computer and your computer's LAN ip .

Answer (score 1):

The mysql user you are using is not having the access permission to the server. Provide the access like

```
GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@'162.54.10.20' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

Where foo is the database name , bar is the user.
You may also consider creating new mysql user to access from your machine.
I hope this helped. For more information check out http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/remotemysql.htm .